# How to get the meeting room resources through MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have been fiddling with the Microsoft Graph API for sometime now in the context of finding a meeting room.

While I could retrieve the list of meeting rooms using the following api call

```
/v1.0/me/people?$filter=personType%2fsubclass+eq+%27Room%27
```

I wonder if I could fetch the attributes associated with the meeting rooms (like meeting room capacity , projector available etc.,) which have been custom added when creating a meeting room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/people` method isn't a reliable source for rooms , but there is a `/beta` endpoint for [findRooms](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms) and [findRoomLists](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findroomlists).

That said, it unfortunately isn't possible to retrieve the extended resource properties such as `msExchResourceCapacity`, `msExchResourceDisplay` or `msExchResourceMetaData. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this as a feature suggestion.

Comment: thanks, I have raised a feature request ! Hope to see it implemented in sometime.